# Driver for old wireless card

Tags: drivers

I have an old buffalo WLI2-PCI-G545 model wireless card and Ubuntu won't recognize it. I was wondering if there was some way I could rig it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=896855&page=3)
Load the driver into ndiswrapper:
Code:

sudo ndiswrapper -i /media/cdrom0/Bin/Driver/CBG54/WIN2000/netg54s.inf

1. Load the ndiswrapper module:
   Code:

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper

1. Does the interface show up? It should:

Code:

iwconfig wlan0

If not, it might not be called wlan0 (I don't see why not, but my card doesn't do this right either). The way to check is to list all the cards:
Code:

ifconfig -a

and look for the MAC address listed as "hwaddr". According to what you posted, the address you should look for is 00:16:01:7d:ea:7e. If that isn't in there, it's not working.

1. Assuming you can find it, try scanning. If it's not called wlan0, then change wlan0 in everything below to what it's called (eth1 or something like that).

Code:

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

A more in depth how to is also avaliable [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=201902)

Comment: im going to try this now will post results in a few

Comment: Its saying ndiswraper not found

Comment: Just install it ;)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Comment: the only cards its showing is eth0 and lo

Comment: Does # sudo lspci | grep wli2 shows anything?

Comment: lspci returns this http://pastebin.com/v9ibzpAw

Comment: grepp wli2 doesnt return anything

Comment: The relevant line is 06:04.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 03)

It means the module is there and the card is recognized. Take a look here for a possible solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98581/bcm4306-b43-legacy-driver-installed-but-firmware-missing-error

Comment: do i need to uninstall ndiswrapper before following that tutorial?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: my friend, you are AMAZING! I havent used ubuntu for about a year and a half now because of this problem. I wish i could do more than just thank you lol but THANKS!!

Comment: @skeetDroid you are most welcome. Just mark the post as valid so others can take profit.